# Header is Not Displaying on Title Page

Tags: header-footer

The header is not displaying on the title page for some reason. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[top=.25in, bottom=.75in, left=.5in, right=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{Form A}}
\author{\textbf{Brad}}
\date{2018-19}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\coverlhead{Math 110}
\coverchead{Exam 1}
\coverrhead{Fall 2018}

\begin{coverpages}

\begin{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center} 
\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name and Period:\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace{5mm}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Student ID Number:\enspace\hrulefill}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
Answer the questions in the spaces provided. If you run out of room
for an answer, continue on the back of the page.}}}
\end{coverpages}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Which header do you mean? Can you please add an screenshot of your result and please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've adjusted the margins so much that the header falls outside the page boundary. Removing (or adjusting) your [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) margins fixes this.

I've added some updates to your code below (including the above suggestion):

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{Form A}}
\author{\textbf{Brad}}
\date{2018-19}
\maketitle

\coverlhead{Math 110}
\coverchead{Exam 1}
\coverrhead{Fall 2018}
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}

\begin{coverpages}

\begin{center}

  \vspace{5mm}

  \gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center} 

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth]{Name and Period:\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace{5mm}

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth]{Student ID Number:\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{center}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
    Answer the questions in the spaces provided. If you run out of room
    for an answer, continue on the back of the page.}}}
\end{center}

\end{coverpages}

\end{document}
```